# Can't insert date into SQL table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, insert, ora-01861

I've created the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE match(
match_id NUMBER(4,0), 
match_date DATE, 
attendance NUMBER(6,0), 
stadium_name VARCHAR2(40), 
tournament_id NUMBER(3,0),
CONSTRAINT match_id_pk PRIMARY KEY(match_id),
CONSTRAINT match_stadium_name_fk FOREIGN KEY(stadium_name) 
           REFERENCES stadium(stadium_name));
```

I attempt to insert the following line:

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(1001, '20130515', 90000, 'American Airlines Arena', 001);
```

Everything I've found tells me the format is YYYYMMDD.  However I keep getting ORA-01861: literal does not match format string.

After using (`DESCRIBE match`) it says the length is only 7.  I thought it was supposed to be 10.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Have you tried supplying the date as `'05/15/2013'`

Comment: The length of what is only 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, the format `YYYYMMDD` is probably not the database date format (you should look for `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` to see what's the db date format).

But there's a `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` at the system level and a (maybe other) `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` at the session level.

You can achieve what you want using `TO_DATE` and specifying the format :

```
INSERT INTO match VALUES(1001, TO_DATE('20130515', 'YYYYMMDD'), 90000, 'American Airlines Arena', 001);
```

Comment: Great! thank you very much.  My text only seems to mention about querying with the TO_DATE I didn't know you could use it in an insert.